# neo4j javascript visualization

Tags: javascript, neo4j, visualization

Which library should be used to draw visualizations using javascript querying Neo4J Backend via REST API.

Found the following examples, but confused if they are maintained and the correct ones to use.

```
# Alchemy  
    https://www.technologyscout.net/2016/08/graph-libraries-alchemy-js/
    https://github.com/vgoebbels/graphexamples

# GRAPH GIST 
    https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/graphgist-cms
```

I have a need to draw 4 or 5 charts, couple of Pie / Bar charts , one spider chart and Dependency map (sort of neo4j traversing - dependencies already mapped in neo4j). Appreciate if correct library can be suggested and pointed to examples.

Require an open source version (not a paid version like Tablaue etc). 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Alchemy.js
2. Sigma.js

I have used Alchemy.js with neo4j and both are open source libraries.